# create epub file in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2, epub

i am new to iPad development. I am making iPad applications. In my application i want to create an epub file using Xcode 4.2, is there any demo tutorial available for making ePub file using Xcode. I have searched in google but i havn't found any thing which starts from basic..

can any one give me basic ideas, how to start ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any code examples which shows how to generate ePub in objective c, but ePub is pretty easy format. It's zip file with structurized content based on xml files http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/Tutorial.shtml
You can build your solution based on projects in other languages, like, in ex. Ruby ePub generator https://github.com/jugyo/eeepub  or C# http://sourceforge.net/projects/epubhub/

Comment: i had downloaded project from                                      http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html   but shows me this errors...

Comment: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/krunal/Downloads/EpubReader/libz.1.2.3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_inflateEnd", referenced from:
_unzCloseCurrentFile in unzip.o

"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
_unzOpenCurrentFile3 in unzip.o

"_get_crc_table", referenced from:
_unzOpenCurrentFile3 in unzip.o
_zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in zip.o

Comment: "_crc32", referenced from:
_unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o
_zipWriteInFileInZip in zip.o
-[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o

"_inflate", referenced from:
_unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o

"_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
_zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in zip.o

"_deflate", referenced from:
_zipWriteInFileInZip in zip.o
_zipCloseFileInZipRaw in zip.o

"_deflateEnd", referenced from:
_zipCloseFileInZipRaw in zip.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


how to solve this any idea ?

Comment: I didn't know this project. Maybe you create another question with this errors. As I see, this project has some dependencies, and I don't know if this libraries are in project.